# Accessing dynamically added control from GridView Footer row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have GridView control in my asp.net page with auto generated fields
there is only footer template is present under asp:TemplateField.

I can bind this gridview with any of databae table as depend on user
selection. Now want to add new record in database so I have added text
boxes on footer template cells at runtime depend on number of columns
on table. But when I accessing these text boxes from footer template
on gridview_RowCommand event its not retriving textbox control.

this is the code:

```
   SGridView.ShowFooter = True
    For i As Integer = 0 To ctrList.Count
        Dim ctr As Control = CType(ctrList.Item(i), Control)
        SGridView.FooterRow.Cells(i + 1).Controls.Add(ctr)
    Next
```

the ctrList contain Controls textBox, checkbox dropdowlist ect.

there is all ok

but when i wont to get the text or value or checked value of controls i can't cast the controls in rowcommand event

Here is the code:

If e.CommandName = "Add" Then

```
    Dim ctrList As ControlCollection = SGridView.FooterRow.Controls

    For Each ctr As Control In ctrList

        If TypeOf ctr Is TextBox Then
            Dim name As TextBox = CType(ctr, TextBox)
            Dim val As String = name.Text
        End If
    Next
End If
```

this excample is for the textBox control.

Plese suggest me how can I get footer control textboxes. So that I can
save data in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create your Controls in the Grdiview's RowCreated Event which will be raised on every Postback.

```
Private Sub Grid1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Grid1.RowCreated
      Select Case e.Row.RowType
          Case DataControlRowType.Footer
          'add controls to row
      End Select
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with Dynamic controls you have to keep a close eye on the .**net page lifecycle.**

Control data is bound in the Load event, so your not able to access postback data in that event when your doing your conrol generation in the Load event too. I usualy try to create dynamic controls in the Init of the page, and do any values processing on the LoadComplete or PreRender event so I can make sure they have recieved their values from the postback before you try to read them.

Take a look at the full description of the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) events and whats going on. This should help you navigate the creation and use of Dynamic generated controls.

Comment: I have added the creation of footer at PageInit, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Did you try moving the access of the control value into a later even than the page load?